# How i can catch the exception message in React Native?

Tags: react-native

In my frontend (React Native) i'm trying to catch this message with try/catch:

```
try {
    const headers = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
    const {data} = yield call(api.post, '/respostaquiz', awnserQuiz, headers);
  } catch (error) {
    console.tron.log(error);
}
```

But when i look in the `console.tron.log(error)` i don't find the message that i defined in my custom exception:

> {
>     "message": "Request failed with status code 400",
>     "name": "Error",
>     "stack": "createError@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:207509:26\nsettle@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:207499:25\nhandleLoad@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:207403:15\ndispatchEvent@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:32304:31\nsetReadyState@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31373:27\n__didCompleteResponse@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31215:29\nemit@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:3318:42\n__callFunction@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2650:49\nhttp://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2363:31\n__guard@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2604:15\ncallFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2362:21\ncallFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]",
>     "config": {
>       "url": "https://xxx.herokuapp.com/respostaquiz",
>       "method": "post",
>       "data": "{\"id_quiz\":807,\"start_date_time\":\"2020-01-29T09:54:23.000Z\",\"end_date_time\":\"2020-01-29T09:54:34.000Z\",\"percentage_correct\":33.33333333333333,\"questions\":[{\"id\":1602,\"resposta\":\"sDFASDF\"},{\"id\":1603,\"resposta\":\"CAT\"},{\"id\":1604,\"resposta\":\"1\"}]}",
>       "headers": {
>         "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
>         "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
>         "Authorization": "Bearer xxx"
>       },
>       "baseURL": "https://xxx.herokuapp.com",
>       "transformRequest": [
>         " transformRequest() "
>       ],
>       "transformResponse": [
>         " transformResponse() "
>       ],
>       "timeout": 0,
>       "adapter": " xhrAdapter() ",
>       "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
>       "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
>       "maxContentLength": -1,
>       "validateStatus": " validateStatus() "
>     }
>   }

How i can get this error message?

[image]

Comment: const {data} = yield call(api.post, '/respostaquiz', awnserQuiz, headers); do console.log('data',data) after api call and see what you are gettin inside it

Comment: @Prakhash don't console anything because this go in the catch() and the function exit

Comment: what you are trying to achieve here ??

Comment: i need the error exception message: "Não foi possível encontrar quiz com o id especificado" this show in the postman, but when i try to console in my catch i don't find this message

Comment: how you are returning response from api

Comment: add your api call as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle errors in fetch() responses with Redux-Saga?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007935/how-to-handle-errors-in-fetch-responses-with-redux-saga)